# What's the construct between <> in the following Objective-C called?

Tags: objective-c

What's the name of the construct starting from `<` and ending with `>` in the following Objective-C code:

```
@interface MyNavigationController : UINavigationController <CCDirectorDelegate>
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a *protocol*, which is equivalent to a Java *interface*, and declares that the class *conforms* to the protocol.

Answer (score 2):

The angle brackets ('<' & '>') is the syntax to indicate that 'MyNavigationController' class adopts the protocol 'CCDirectorDelegate'.

```
@interface MyNavigationController : UINavigationController <CCDirectorDelegate>
@end
```

This means that any instance of 'MyNavigationController' will respond not only to the methods declared specifically in the interface, but that 'MyNavigationController' also provides implementations for the required methods in 'CCDirectorDelegate'. There’s no need to redeclare the protocol methods in the class interface—the adoption of the protocol is sufficient.

Here's a example of adopting multiple protocols,

```
<CCDirectorDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate,UITableViewDelegate>
```

You can read more about them [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH11-SW3).

So, the construct between the two angular brackets is known as 'Adopting protocols' or 'Conforming to protocols'.